# Google Chrome Packaged App - FTP Upload

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, ftp, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a Chrome APP which can upload files to known FTP server, but when ever I'm trying to send the file my code only creates a File with name specified with 0KB

All guidance appreciated.

```
function ab2str(buf) {
   return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
 }
function str2ab(str) {
   var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length); // 2 bytes for each char
   var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
   for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
     bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return buf;
 }

chrome.sockets.tcp.create( {persistent:false }, function(createInfo) {
    socketID = createInfo.socketId;
    chrome.sockets.tcp.connect( socketID, IP, PORT, onCallback);
});

function onCallback( result ){
    console.log( "onCallback", result );    
};

chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
var d = ab2str( info.data );

if (d.indexOf("220 ")>-1){

    // send user.
    console.log( "send " + ftp_username);
    chrome.sockets.tcp.send( socketID, str2ab("USER "+ftp_username+"\n"), onCallback );
}
if (d.indexOf("331 ")>-1){
    // send password.
    console.log( "send password");

    chrome.sockets.tcp.send( socketID, str2ab("PASS "+ftp_password+"\n"), onCallback );
}
if (d.indexOf("230 ")>-1){

    chrome.sockets.tcp.send( socketID, str2ab("PASV\n"), function(e, outstream) {
       chrome.sockets.tcp.send( socketID, str2ab("STOR icon.png\n"), onCallback );     

    } );
}

});
```

Comment: You did not show any code that would actually transfer the file, did you? What is `onCallback`? This question is incomplete; please take time to edit it, including all _relevant_ code.

Comment: @Xan: thanks for reply i have updated my code snippet can please  suggest me a way to upload file to FTP server using Chrome Sockets

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question. Your code does not transmit any data; how did you expect it to be any other result when, I quote, "trying to send the file"? If your **real** question is "I want to send a file, this is what I have so far but I don't know how to actually send the file", please formulate it as such; also, show how you can access the file itself (where is it stored?).

Comment: Also, I can recommend looking at an [existing implementation](https://github.com/MikeCostello/chrome-app-ftp/blob/master/ftp-client.js#L140) (and of course [the protocol itself](http://www.ncftp.com/libncftp/doc/ftp_overview.html))